# What is the gen_server's State life cycle

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

I am new learner on Erlang, I have questions about Erlang variable's life cycle.

Reference from [Erlang gen_server comunication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859241/erlang-gen-server-comunication)

```
-module(wy).
-compile(export_all).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-record(state, {id ,m, succ, pred}).

start(Name, M) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, Name}, ?MODULE, [Name, M], []).

init([Name, M]) ->
    {ok, #state{id = Name, m = M}}.

handle_call({get_server_info}, _Frome, State) ->
    {reply, State, State};
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.


get_server_info(ServerName) ->
    gen_server:call(ServerName, {get_server_info}).
```

What is the Variable "State" life cycle?

We can see variable "State" is reused from handle_call and handle_cast. First of all, are these "State" is the same one which is initialized from init() function `"#state{id = Name, m = M}"`?

If so, is this "State" a global variable? When will this "State" be destroyed.

Does Erlang have global variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, although I think it's worth pointing out that the variable `State` is *technically* not the same everywhere but it does reference the same *value* everywhere. Each of your callbacks (i.e. `inti/1`, `handle_call/3`, etc.) receive `State` as a parameter and they must return a (possibly new) `State` as part of their results.

To understand how this works, you need to know what `gen_server` does. In an super-extremely-oversimplified way, what gen_server is doing when you call `gen_server:start_link/4` is:

```
% Ignoring stuff here, for simplicity
start_link(_Name, Mod, InitArg, _Options) ->
  spawn(
    fun() ->
      {ok, State} = Mod:init(InitArg),
      loop(Mod, State) %% This is where the result of your init/1 function goes
    end).

loop(Mod, State) ->
  NextState =
    receive
      {call, From, Msg} ->
        % Here, it gives you the current state and expects you to return
        % a new one.
        {reply, Reply, NewState} = Mod:handle_call(Msg, From, State),
        NewState;
      {cast, Msg} ->
        % Here, it gives you the current state and expects you to return
        % a new one.
        {noreply, NewState} = Mod:handle_cast(Msg, State),
        NewState;
      Info ->
        % Here, it gives you the current state and expects you to return
        % a new one.
        {noreply, NewState} = Mod:handle_info(Msg, State),
        NewState;
      {stop, Reason} ->
        Mod:terminate(Reason, State),
        exit(Reason)
    end,
  loop(Mod, NextState). % Then it keeps on looping with the new state
```

As you can see, the value of the `State` is local to the gen_server process, it is passed to each callback and it's *replaced* with the result of each callback to keep looping until the server is terminated.
Of course, gen_server's code is not that simple ([This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MRMnaqtyeg&t=6s) provides a great explanation for this - in Spanish, I know, sorry).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, Brujo. I have one more follow up question. When call, cast, info, setting State simultaneously from different process, will State capture all changes from different process? When cast() set value A into State, the same time another cast() set value B into State, before both that State is empty. After value set, what will be saved into State, A, B or AB both? @Brujo Benavides

Comment: Yeah, as you can see in my code, even when messages reach our server asynchronously, the loop only processes one at the time and the evaluation of each callback is synchronic (i.e. code doesn't move on until something is returned from `handle_*`).

Furthermore, to be painfully explicit, `gen_server:cast/2` does not set the state, it only sends a message to the server process. In our example it will look like `cast(Server, Msg) -> Server ! {cast, Msg}.`
That message is received within our `loop` and that's when `Mod:handle_cast/2` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

**State** is the internal state of the gen_server. State can be anything, a single variable to data structure (map, record or list), in this case a record. use record if you have defined set of values, otherwise we can use a map.

Yes, State will initialized in init() function and will be passes as a parameter in each callbacks, you can simply update State value according to your need and set is as new State when sending reply in each callbacks.

State will destroyed along with gen_server process, if gen server killed or exit normally. when exiting with reason normal terminate/3 callback will be called.